# Chrome extension content_scripts v38

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Have a google chrome extension that was working fine -but then v38.

```
"content_scripts":
[
    {
        "matches": [ "https://www.mydomain.com/*" ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": [ "cs_storage.js", "utils.js", "cs_utils.js", "content.js" ]
    }
]
```

The problem is that for a specific page the document_end event doesn't trigger.

Used to work pre v38.

Once one that page - if I reload the page - then it  triggers.

When one navigates to that page - there's a redirect and takes a little bit of time 2-3 seconds.

I did intercept the document_start event and that does trigger - but not document_end for this page.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure about the cause of the problem, are you certain that the *site itself* didn't change behavior in way that breaks your extension?

Comment: Provide more information, it's hard to help you only with this 4 lines of code...

Comment: I'm pretty sure nothings changed on the site itself. But when the website page is being loaded - there's an error on jquery load. but that shouldn't matter to chrome code. As I wrote before I do get the document_start event but not document_end on this specific page - but works on other pages. It's an internal company website w/ password access - so can't post link.

Comment: @dashman Try to create a static HTML page and try to see whether the bug is reproducible on it. If you have tried really hard and you cannot create such an example, **and** you are certain that this is a bug in Chromium, then you could give me temporary access to your company's web page (e.g. via TeamViewer) in order to debug the problem. If you cannot do any of that, then we really cannot help you any further.